# use std::logical_and to combine two conditions

Tags: c++

```
    int nums[] = {7, 6, 12, 9, 29, 1, 67, 3, 3, 8, 9, 77};
    std::vector<int> vecInts(&nums[0], &nums[0] + sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]));

    int countBoost = 0;

    // (i > 5 && i <=10)
    countBoost = std::count_if(vecInts.begin(), vecInts.end(),
                      boost::bind(std::logical_and<bool>(), 
                                  boost::bind(std::greater<int>(),    _1, 5),
                                         boost::bind(std::less_equal<int>(), _1, 10))
                          );
```

Now, I need to implement the same logical with pure STL. How can I do that?

I have tried the following code and it doesn't work:

```
int countSTL   = std::count_if(vecInts.begin(), vecInts.end(),
                           std::logical_and<bool>(std::bind2nd(std::greater<int>(), 5), std::bind2nd(std::less_equal<int>(), 10))                               
                          );
```

Thank you

// Updated //

```
In Effective STL Item 43, Meyers indicates as follows:

vector<int>::iterator i = find_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
           compose2(logical_and<bool>(), bind2nd(greater<int>(), x),
                                         bind2nd(less<int>(), y)));
```

> But compose2 is NOT a standard function object adapter.

Comment: Well, you could try changing `boost::bind` to `std::bind`.

Comment: Is std::bind a new function to C++11? I would like to see how to implement with `std::bind1st` or `std::bind2nd` if that is possible.

Comment: In C++03, use `std::bind1st`, `std::bind2nd` and `std::compose2`. See [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/logical_and.html) for an example.

Comment: Just tried, VS2010 doesn't support this.

Comment: `compose2` isn't part of C++03 unfortunately.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but VS2010 does support lambda expressions which are much nicer than this `bind` nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

With "pure" C++03 std - you can only do this with using of additional bool arrays:
Store all results from `bind2nd(greater<int>(), x)` to one bool array, same for `less` in second array. The `logical_and` result to third array. For dynamic size - use std::vector instead of simple raw arrays. Or just copy(steal) implementation of SGI STL `compose2<>` from http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_function.h.

```
int main() {
    int nums[] = {7, 6, 12, 9, 29, 1, 67, 3, 3, 8, 9, 77};
    const size_t NUMS_SIZE = sizeof(nums) / sizeof(*nums);
    bool nums_greater[NUMS_SIZE];
    bool nums_less[NUMS_SIZE];
    bool nums_greater_and_less[NUMS_SIZE];

    int x = 3;
    int y = 20;
    transform(nums, nums + NUMS_SIZE, nums_greater, bind2nd(greater<int>(), x));
    transform(nums, nums + NUMS_SIZE, nums_less, bind2nd(less<int>(), y));
    transform (nums_greater, nums_greater+NUMS_SIZE, nums_less, nums_greater_and_less,
               logical_and<bool>() );

    int countBoost = 0;

    countBoost = count(nums_greater_and_less, nums_greater_and_less + NUMS_SIZE, true);

    cout << countBoost  << endl;
}
```